# Spawn in nodejs for a unix command with spaces in parameters

Tags: node.js, linux, parameters, spawn

I would like to execute the following command using nodejs Spawn on a Debian system :

`/usr/bin/apt-get upgrade -s | tail -1 | cut -f1 -d' '`

I want to use spawn and not exec because of future use of root only commands and i don't want to allow a full shell access (i will update the visudo file with correct commands) 
Here is my code

```
  const apt = spawn('/usr/bin/apt-get', ['upgrade', '-s']);
  const tail = spawn('tail', ['-1']);
  const cut = spawn('cut', ['-f1', '-d" "']);

  apt.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    tail.stdin.write(data);
  });

  tail.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    cut.stdin.write(data);
  });

  cut.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data.toString());
  });


  apt.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log("apt stderr: ${data}");
  });

  tail.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log("tail stderr: ${data}");
  });

  cut.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log("cut stderr: ${data}");
  });

  apt.on('close', (code) => {
    if (code !== 0) {
      console.log("apt process exited with code ${code}");
    }
  });

  tail.on('close', (code) => {
    if (code !== 0) {
      console.log("tail process exited with code ${code}");
    }
  });

  cut.on('close', (code) => {
    if (code !== 0) {
      console.log("cut process exited with code ${code}");
    }
  });

  res.status(200).json('');
```

Once executed i have an error because of the '-d" "' parameter that is not recognized. I try escaping the space with a double \ or split the parameter in both but still errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should just be:

```
const cut = spawn('cut', ['-f1', '-d ']);
```

No double quotes *or* backslash escapes -- those are for the use *of the shell*, not `cut`, and there's no shell here.

This makes dealing with unknown filenames (for your future use cases) particularly easy: When your strings are passed as arguments (to software that doesn't misuse them my running `eval`-equivalent code later), you don't need to quote, escape, sanitize, or otherwise modify them before they can be passed as data.

(That is to say -- when you tell your shell `cut -f1 -d" "`, the actual syscall it invokes to start that `cut` process, in C syntax, looks like `execve("/usr/bin/cut", {"cut", "-f1", "-d ", NULL}, environ)`; the quotes were syntactic, consumed by the shell when it used them to make the decision that the space after the `-d` should be part of the same literal argument).

Comment: Thanks Charles ! That worked and i also understood why ;-) I missed the shell needs
Another point : that means that for a command like `/bin/grep -P '^\d+ upgraded'`i would have to write it like `spawn('grep', ['-P', '"^\\d+ ', 'upgraded"'])` ?

Comment: `'^\d+ upgraded'` is parsed by the shell to a single string (that's one of the effects of the syntactic single quotes), so it'd be `spawn('grep', ['-P', '^\\d+ upgraded'])` to write that same single string in JavaScript.

Comment: Some places to start re: understanding how this works on the shell side might be http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes or http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting, and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashParser