# Get full command-line string from child_process.spawn

Tags: node.js, child-process, spawn

I'm spawning a process with child_process.spawn().  How can I view the exact command line that is executed (including all command-line parameters passed into the spawn function)?

Here's my example that isn't working:

```
var s = require('child_process');
var p = s.spawn('ffmpeg', ['-probesize 1024', '-i "rtsp://192.168.1.10:554/11"', 'test.h264']);
```

When I capture the stderr, I get a message "Unrecognized option 'probesize 1024'.  However, if I run ffmpeg from the command line, it works fine.  So I need to see exactly how the command-line options are being mangled before being sent to FFMPEG in order to debug this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var p = s.spawn('ffmpeg', [
    '-probesize',
    '1024',
    '-i',
    'rtsp://192.168.1.10:554/11',
    'test.h264'
]);
```

Command line arguments that have a space between them but are coherent, still need to be separated. So there's needs to be a space between `-probesize` and `1024`

**Update**

If you would like to keep the coherent arguments together, add `shell: true` to the options object:

```
var p = s.spawn('ffmpeg',
    [
        '-probesize 1024',
        '-i "rtsp://192.168.1.10:554/11"',
        'test.h264'
    ],
    {
        shell: true
    }
);
```

Comment: Your answer works, but why?  I thought the arguments were simply passed to the child process as a string, so a space is a space... Can you help me understand why this isn't correct?

Comment: Also, how can I pass strings with question-mark characters?  For example, when running ffmpeg with rtsp://192.168.1.11:554/stream0?username=admin&password=123456, I must quote this.  But if I add quotes when passing via spawn, I get an error.

Comment: Honestly, I never went too deep into that so I'm not the right person to answer that :( . I remembered it from the last time. What I recall is: if you would call it with `{shell: true}` as an option, what you did first would be possible (I'll update the answer in a second). From what I understood it mimicks calling a program in `C`, I think this answer might give you a better starting point to further research it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46254602/spawn-in-nodejs-for-a-unix-command-with-spaces-in-parameters

Comment: This is not an answer to the original question. The original question was "how do I obtain a particular bit of debugging information by myself", not "please debug this specific case for me".

Comment: @SzczepanHołyszewski : I'm looking foward to your answer. I'll give you an upvote if you show "how [to] obtain a particular bit of debugging information by myself"

Answer (score 0):

Old question I know...but one idea I had, which might answer the OP's question

```
const cp = require('child_process');

var sp = cp.spawn( 'cmd', [ '/C' , 'echo', 'ffmpeg', 
    '-probesize',
    '1024',
    '-i',
    'rtsp://192.168.1.10:554/11',
    'test.h264'
]);

sp.stdout.on( "data" , (d) => {
     console.log( `${d}`);
});
```

which will echo the cmd to the console...

```
ffmpeg -probesize 1024 -i rtsp://192.168.1.10:554/11 test.h264
```