# passing options in execFileSync fails for ffmpeg

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I am trying to write a small scripts to automate the creation of video files. I have it almost working but stuck at one part, following is my node js code:

```
let str1 = "-c:v libvpx -i sourceVideos/a1.mkv -c:v libvpx -i sourceVideos/a2.mkv -c:v libvpx -i sourceVideos/a3.mkv";
let str2 = "[1]setpts=PTS+5.00/TB[a2];[2]setpts=PTS+10.00/TB[a3];[0][a2]overlay[o2];[o2][a3]overlay";
let outFile = 'validout.mp4';
const masterStream = execFileSync('ffmpeg', [str1, '-filter_complex', str2, outFile]);

console.log('All processing completed');
```

The above code represents this ffmpeg command to create a video from multiple videos:

```
ffmpeg -c:v libvpx -i sourceVideos/a1.mkv -c:v libvpx -i sourceVideos/a2.mkv -c:v libvpx -i sourceVideos/a3.mkv -filter_complex "[1]setpts=PTS+5.00/TB[a2];[2]setpts=PTS+10.00/TB[a3];[0][a2]overlay[o2];[o2][a3]overlay" validationout.mp4
```

So I have placed the args in str2 and the options/inputs in str1. The problem is that when I pass the inputs with their options in str1 and place it in my execFileSync command it's not parsed by the command. I have also tested for confirmation and if I pass the options in the following format it works in the node js script:

```
//version 1 with separated arguments
const masterStream = execFileSync('ffmpeg', ['-c:v', 'libvpx', '-i', 'sourceVideos/a1.mkv', '-c:v', 'libvpx', '-i', 'sourceVideos/a2.mkv', '-c:v', 'libvpx', '-i', 'sourceVideos/a3.mkv', '-filter_complex', str2, outFile]);
```

**My question is: how can I pass the options/inputs to the execFileSync in str1 so that they can be executed?**

Comment: What happens is if you enable `shell: true` like `execFileSync('ffmpeg), [...args], { shell: true }), ` ?

Comment: hey!!!....it worked...can you elaborate on what changed. I am going to mark this is the correct response. Thanks @axm__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arguments that fit together like `-i sourceVideos/a1.mkv` should be separated (`-i`, `sourceVideos/a1.mkv` if you haven't enabled `shell: true` in the `options` object:

```js
execFileSync('ffmpeg'), ['-i', 'sourceVideos/a1.mkv']) // must be separate
// or
execFileSync('ffmpeg', ['-i sourceVideos/a1.mkv'], { shell: true })
```

This should really have been put in the nodejs docs. Apparently it has to do with how the program is called in `C` on a deeper level. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46254637) for more information.